# How can I simulate the same Window layout as Finder?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, interface-builder

How can I make a window with same basic structure as the Finder window (a menu/source list to the left with icons that can be organized, and the content in a larger view on the right)?

Answer (score 4):

To replicate the content view of the Finder, use:

1. Icon view: NSCollectionView
2. List view: NSOutlineView
3. Column view: NSBrowser
4. CoverFlow: Custom on top, NSOutlineView (list view) below

You can probably find a third-party open-source implementation of CoverFlow for the Mac with a bit of Googling.

As Williham Totland already mentioned, the way to make a source list (sidebar) is NSOutlineView. There are a few questions here on Stack Overflow about getting it to look more like that.

A toolbar is, of course, NSToolbar.

Answer (score 2):

Apple provides sample code to do exactly what you are trying to achieve:

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/SourceView/

As others have pointed out, it uses an `NSOutlineView` for the source list and an `NSCollectionView` for the content.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be confusing 'left' and 'right'. But I digress.

To create a window with a similar structure you would use, for the icons portion, an `NSOutlineView`, if memory serves. You might also be able to use an `NSTableView`.

Unless of course I'm misunderstanding your question; in which case you would use for the right part an `NSCollectionView`, I suppose. You would still use one of the two mentioned above for the source list on the left side.

Comment: When i use NSOutlineView i get those annnoying scrollbars. How can i get it as simple as the Finder Window?

Comment: The Finder's sidebar has scroll bars, too. If you're getting scroll bars, it's because your content is too big for where you put it. If you don't want them, either make the view (including its columns) smaller or make its container bigger.

Comment: Okay, how can i change the background color on the OutlineView?

Comment: Turn off "Show vertical scroller" for the enclosing scroll view in IB or programmatically. Select "Source List" as Highlight for the outline view.

Comment: How can i remove the header: http://mm-hotel.dk/screens/300201e4de9915a4aca40fb3fa36a7a2.png ?

Comment: Mikkel: Turn it off in IB. It's a checkbox on the Attributes (⌘1) Inspector for the outline view.

Answer (score 0):

For the Icon view, you can use `IKImageBrowserView`. The finder uses it internally.